# Can I have titanium leave out code block?

Tags: ios, build, sdk, titanium, appcelerator-titanium

Is it possible to have the titanium build command leave out certain parts of code?
We have a demo version app, and I would like to be able to leave this part out when building for the AppStore so I do not have to take it out by hand.

Does anyone know of a way to do this ?

Thanx for your help.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Is this code you want to have only on Android or is it just code in general that you want to leave out?

When the Appcelerator CLI builds the code it will automatically discard code that does not actually get run by any other code, for example if you have a function like the function below or even just a variable that never gets used when you compile you will see that that code is not even in the final compiled code. This is what I have learned from checking the build for Android and I believe it would be the same for iOS

```
function neverUsed(){ 
  var neverUsedVar = "blank";
}
```

Comment: it is just general code
I would like the build process to leave out specific code blocks if it is building for the store, but leave the code blocks in if the build command is say for an ad hoc profile